# Kendo UI grid getting data from Dynamics CRM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, dynamics-crm-online

I have a strange problem getting data from Dynamics CRM online into a kendo UI data grid , when I inspect with chrome browser, I get sometimes this error

[image]

but when I use CORS this error disappear and I get new error indicating that the request is UNAUTHORIZED 401,

[image]

Please help me with this error, in attachment you find my source code
THANKS A LOT

```
function onReady() {

    $("#btnSearch").kendoButton({
        click: onSearch
    })

    $("#kGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "Application/json",
                    url: 'https://cynapsyscrm.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts',
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    }
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                    delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter
                    delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter

                    return paramMap;
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            'AccountID',
            'AccountName',
            'NumberOfEmployees',
            'Revenue',
            'PrimaryContact',
            'PrimaryContactName'
        ]
      })
  }

  $(document).ready(onReady);
```

Comment: You need to get familiar with [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, you're trying to access a CRM online domain from localhost. You simply can't do that because it is a cross domain issue and I don't think MS will enable "localhost" as an allowed domain :)

Try to deploy it to a test CRM instance or maybe test your code using unit tests.

Hope this helps